# 1000 Animations Performance

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I am making a dictionary that would list 1000 words, and everytime one word is click, a panel will pop up and show 2 UI Object; **Word Selected** and **Animation of that word**.

Example : 
[image]

Performance wise, how should I setup my game object ? Should it be a 1000 inactive gameobject and activate it depending on which word selected ? Or I create one gameobject and change animation programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 1 object and change the animation/ text. Keeping so many objects on screen is very hard to maintain and keep track of

Comment: How do I change animation clip as there would be only one controller per GO without using Mechanim state ?

Comment: Do you use sprite animatins? If so it souldn't be too hard. Just try it out and write an other question if it does not work. You could also create a prefab for every object and just destroy the old one and instantiate a new one everytime the user clicks a word in the dictionary